# Expected value in rock paper scissor

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value

Two players play rock, paper, scissors for 3 wins ( one player wins 3 times). What is the expected value of the number of rounds?

I tried: for the n-th games probability : $$ p(x_n)=2\frac{\binom{n}{3}}{3^n} $$

Therefore my $E(x)\approx 1.8733$ which is too low...

Comment: I don't understand.  You are asking how many times you expect them to play before one of the players has won $3$ games?  How could the answer to that possibly be less than $3$?  Or are you asking something else?

Comment: @lulu that's the problem, the E(x) is not high enough, I think the problem is in how I want to calculate the probability.

Comment: Do we want one player to have won thrice, or thrice *in a row*?

Comment: @RhysHughes not in a row, overall the game

Comment: To be clear:  unless I have forgotten the rules, rock paper scissors is just a $50-50$ matter.  So you can forget the underlying game and just think about a coin toss.

Comment: @lulu not exactly, there is equal $\frac13$ chance of win, loss, and draw. Draws won't count towards either players win count but will inflate the game count we are measuring

Comment: @RhysHughes  Oh, thanks.  Been a very long time since I played.  Yes, the possibility of a draw does inflate the numbers.

Comment: Are you sure $p(x_n)=\textbf{2}\frac{\binom{n}{3}}{3^n}$ instead of $8\frac{\binom{n}{3}}{3^n}$?

Comment: Why would it be 8?

Comment: Note that we must tie for $n-3$ rounds, and 3 rounds must have a decisive winner. There are $\binom{n}{3}$ ways to order these. The probability that we tie for $n-3$ rounds is $\frac{1}{3^{n-3}}$. The probability that we don't tie for $3$ rounds is $\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^3=\frac{8}{3^3}$. Multiplying all three together, we get that the probability of finishing the game on the $n$th round is $\frac{8\binom{n}{3}}{3^n}$.

Comment: @TheBestMagician if I use your method i get $E(x) \approx 7.5$ and sum of the probabilities is 1.5 for 25 rounds.

Comment: Yes, I think this is correct. It seems reasonable.

Comment: @TheBestMagician must there be a tie for $n-3$ rounds? If $A$ is the event the first player wins, $B$ the event the second player wins, and $T$ the event of a tie, then one way to finish the game after $n=8$ rounds is $$ATTTBBAA$$ I think a natural way to approach this problem is by using states.

Comment: @MatthewPilling I am sorry, I have made a grave error. I forgot that we can have a sequence where both players win (best of $3$). Ignore my earlier comments.

Comment: States is a good method, though you can also do it by ignoring ties and then recognizing that, because of ties, we expect it to take $\frac 32$ games to see a W/L.

Comment: So how would you calculate the probability?

Comment: @lulu I know I've told you this before, but you are my absolute favorite member of MSE. I have learned so much from you! Please keep posting. Thank you!

Comment: @MatthewPilling  Very kind of you to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative method that avoids the use of states:

First do the same problem for a fair coin.  In that case the match must be decided in $3,4$ or $5$ games.  It is easy to see that the probability of ending it in $3$ is $\frac 14$ and that the probabilitis of ending in $4$ or $5$ are equal, hence both must be $\frac 38$.  It follows that $$E_{coin}=\frac {33}8$$

Now, the actual game allows for ties.  But we expect exactly $\frac 23$ of any string of games to be non-ties.  Hence $$E_{rps}\times \frac 23=E_{coin}\implies E_{rps}=\frac {99}{16}$$

Which confirms the result obtained by states.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in comments, let's consider the states the game can be in after each round. $S(x,y)$ is the state where player A has won $x$ rounds so far and player B has won $y$ rounds so far. A tie round keeps the game in the same state. And let $T(x,y)$ be the distribution of the number of turns remaining in the game at state $S(x,y)$.

Since the rules and stop condition are symmetric for both players, $T(y,x) = T(x,y)$. When either win count reaches $3$, our overall count is done: $T(x,3)=T(3,y)=0$. When $x<3$ and $y<3$, we get the recursion

$$ E\{T(x,y)\} = 1 + \frac{1}{3} E\{T(x,y)\} + \frac{1}{3} E\{T(x+1,y)\} + \frac{1}{3} E\{T(x,y+1)\} \\
E\{T(x,y)\} = \frac{3}{2} + \frac{1}{2} E\{T(x+1,y)\} + \frac{1}{2} E\{T(x,y+1)\} $$

From here the expected values are easy to compute, going from largest $x$ and $y$ to smallest:

$$E\{T(2,2)\} = \frac 32 \\
E\{T(2,1)\} = \frac 32 + \frac 34 = \frac 94 \\
E\{T(2,0)\} = \frac 32 + \frac 98 = \frac{21}{8} \\
E\{T(1,1)\} = \frac 32 + \frac 98 + \frac 98 = \frac{15}{4} \\
E\{T(1,0)\} = \frac 32 + \frac{21}{16} + \frac{15}{8} = \frac{75}{16} \\
E\{T(0,0)\} = \frac 32 + \frac{75}{32} + \frac{75}{32} = \frac{99}{16}$$

The last line is the expected total number of rounds for the whole game, $99/16$.